# How can I display <TAB> as bars in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I want to know is it possible to display the `<tab>`  as | (bars) when coding in vim like this  [image] Are there any ways to show them.

Please any solution other than `set listchars` and `set list` as it affects eol and spaces.

Comment: _"Please any solution other than set listchars and set list as it affects eol and spaces."_ - what do you mean by "affects"? You can assign characters for the trailing spaces: `set list listchars=tab:\|\ ,trail:•,extends:#,nbsp:.`, but the setting will not "affect" the content of the file. You can ignore the trailing spaces, if you like. You can configure the look of these characters as you like.

Comment: My problem is that the spaces and eol will also be displayed and I want to keep them which makes the file so crowded.

Comment: From `:h listchars`: _`eol:c`  Character to show at the end of each line.  When omitted, there is no extra character at the end of the line._ The same is true for `trail`

Comment: That screenshot is a Vim screenshot so **of course** it's possible. Why don't you ask to the "stephane" who made that screenshot how he did it?

Comment: I was waiting for you to tell me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```vim
:set list
:set lcs=tab:\|\  " the last character is space!
```

The `tab` setting consists of two characters: `|` and a space. The first character is used once. The second character is repeated to fill the space that the tab normally occupies. See `:h lcs`.

Sample result:

[image]

However, setting the second character to space is not very helpful, as it is difficult to distinguish spaces followed by a tab, for instance. Consider changing it to another character, e.g.:

```vim
:set list listchars=tab:\|\-
```

Sample result:

[image]

Comment: lcs is listchars :/

Comment: @Sabrina, yes, and it does exactly what you have shown on the screenshot. Check it out.

Comment: I already know this solution: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/See_the_tabs_in_your_file